# Adjust UILabel size based on size Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to adjust my label size based on screen size using swift.  I'm using the dynamic layout and cannot figure it out.  Essentially what I am looking to do is shrink the text/font size to fit within my frame.

Comment: Be more specific. Label size? Do you mean the frame, font size, etc? You're using auto layout and having a hard time with constraints or.... ?

Comment: label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true ??

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all in the storyboard.

Add constraints between the leading and trailing edges of the label and its superview. (Something like `|-[label]-|` in the visual format.) This will adjust the width of the label as the width of its superview changes.

If you want the font size to adjust as well, you can set the Autoshrink item in the storyboard to Minimum Font Scale and set an appropriate value (0.5 is the default).